# I want to reset a C++ struct stat, can I use the stat() syntax in some way?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14

I like to explicitly initialize my variables for safety (when you write a lot of code, it generally makes it a lot safer, as in, your code doesn't crash as much in the end.)

For most types, whether structures or basic C++ types like integers, I can write the following:

```
time_t now = time();  // initialize now to 0

struct foo
{
    int param_;
};
foo f = foo();  // initialize f.param_ to 0
```

When I try to do the same initialization for `struct stat`, I get in trouble:

```
struct stat s = stat();
```

In this case the C++ compiler tells me that `stat()` is a function and it requires X parameters to be called.

Is that a shortfall of that initialization syntax?

Note: I know I can reset the structure using `memset()` as in:

```
struct stat s;
memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));
```

Only that's useless in a case like this one:

```
struct foo
{
    struct stat   s_ = stat();
};
```

I also know I can write my own initialization function as in the following:

```
inline struct stat init_stat()
{
    struct stat s;
    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));
    return s;
}
struct foo
{
    struct stat s_ = init_stat();
};
```

I just would prefer a cleaner way as with `time_t()` or `foo()` above.

Comment: I believe stat is a function defined somewhere in Linux headers . That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: How is `stat` defined?  How is `stat()` defined?

Comment: @NathanOliver When you `#include <sys/stat.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregate initialization, as it doesn't require you to specify the type you want to initialize your variable with:

```
struct stat s_{};
// or
struct stat s_ = {};
```

Comment: Do you know that `stat` can be initialized in such a way?

Comment: @NathanOliver, this is the same as my `memset(&s_, 0, sizeof(_s));`

Comment: @NathanOliver Is there any reason why it can't? It's a C struct after all, so all of its members are default constructible.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Until the OP commented that it was from `<sys/stat.h>` I had no idea what it was.  If it was a type without a default constructor then empty braced list initialization would not work.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah ok, that makes sense. :)